# Web API authentication on server

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am writing an Windows App that will communicate with Web API. Here is how I am making a call :

```
HttpClient client = null;
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { PreAuthenticate = true, Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials };
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseAddress);
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.UserName);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Tickets/AuthenticateUser").Result;
```

I am passing the currently logged credentials. I have written a filter which connects to db and checks if the username exists. The code :

```
public class BasicAuthenticationWindowsAppAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters..AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
        else
        {
            string authToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
            string Handle = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authToken));
            GenericIdentity gi = new GenericIdentity(Handle);
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(gi, null);
            HttpContext.Current.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
            Amo_MasterDataEntities amoMasterDataContext = new Amo_MasterDataEntities();
            var query = from a in amoMasterDataContext.allassociatemasters
                        where a.Handle == Handle
                        select a;
            //If Handle is present in AMOMasterData.AllAssociatemaster table

            if (query.Count() > 0)
            {
                //TicketsController tc = new TicketsController();
                string assocId = "", fName ="", lName = "";
                bool authenticated = false;
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    assocId = item.AssociateID;
                    fName = item.FirstName;
                    lName = item.LastName;
                    authenticated = true;
                }
                AuthInfo info = new AuthInfo();
                info.AssociateId = assocId;
                info.FirstName = fName;
                info.LastName = lName;
                info.IsAuthenticated = authenticated;
                actionContext.Request.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("AuthInfo", info));
                base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);

            }
            //else return error
            else
            actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

        }
    }
}
```

When I run the web service in my local system it works. But when I deploy the web service on server it is giving me 401 Unauhorized Message.

I have enabled both Basic and Windows Authentication in IIS and Web.config contains `<authentication mode="Windows" />`

**Edit :**
I am able to access the Web API Methods from the server where I have deployed.
But When I am calling the Web API from a windows client on another Machine it is throwing 401 error.

Should I use CORS? If yes please let me know how?

Can anybody give me a solution for this.

Comment: Well does it work if you take out `<authentication mode="" />` ?

Comment: Hi Mark. I tried removing <authentication mode="" /> still getting a 401.

Comment: Did you try to throw in any kind of logging in your `OnAuthorization` method?

Comment: No Mark. I have not set up any logging. The way I am using HttpClient is correct right. Because In some posts online i saw thatHttpClient may not send AuthorizationHeader properly or something like that.

Comment: Well how are you going to troubleshoot your issue then? lol

Comment: I am new to this. I will try to set up logging. It would be nice if you can guide me if any common error is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason,..

I was not passing the handler to constructor of HttpClient that was the problem. So in above code replace :

```
client = new HttpClient();
```

with :

```
client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Such a silly mistake. Sorry for the trouble.